# Create dynamic variables from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have a .txt file with some integers in it (separated by spaces, e.g '22 1 3 49'). I want ajax to the file as an array/list and then save each as a JavaScript variable.
This code currently reads everything from the file all as one and changes every `<p>` tag in the HTML to whatever was in there:

```
var num1;
var num2;
var num3;
var num4;
function loadDoc(){
    $.ajax({url: "ajax_info.txt", success: function(result){
        $("p").html(result);
    }});
}
```

So given a text file with '22 1 3 49', my JavaScript would have variables num1 = 22; num2 = 1; etc...

I've never used Ajax before so help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solution doesn't really involve jquery just javascript string functions basically. You can use the **split** function of the string object and deliver a seperator(in your case a space). This method will return an array, which elements you can assign to your variables. Example:
`var numbersArray = result.split(" ");`
`num1 = numbersArray[0];`
`num2 = numbersArray[1];` etc...

Comment: `function loadDoc(){
    $.ajax({url: "ajax_info.txt", success: function(result){
        var numbersArray = result.split(" ");
        $("p").html(result);
    }});
}`

Is it really as simple as that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with dynamic variable creation,change the num to whatever

```js
var result = '22 1 3 49';
var arr = result.split(" ");

for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
window['num'+(i+1)] =   arr[i];
}

console.log(' num1= ' + num1 +' num2= ' + num2 + ' num3= ' + num3 + ' num4= ' + num4 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give this code a try:

```
obj = {
    var1: result.split(" ")[0],
    var2: result.split(" ")[1],
    var3: result.split(" ")[2]
};
```